# Why and how hibernate is called as a lightweight ORM tool?

Tags: hibernate, orm

What does exactly mean by light weight ORM tool ?
is it for memory efficient ? or for simplicity ? or for fast behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

Here light weight is in terms of how focused the tool is in solving a particular problem. It is "light" in the terms that it does not have unneeded functionality for its specific purpose of Object Relational mapping. The term is relative and was used in comparison with EJB 2 which gave a lot more features for enterprise app development. EJB 3 has evolved in becoming more modular and supports the JPA standard and can be configured with Hibernate as its provider. Still EJB 3 provides a lot more features than just ORM.

If your specific need requires only an ORM tool, then Hibernate is light weight compared to EJB.

Also, make sure to decouple the words "lightweight" and "ORM" in your question.
To rephrase your question correctly: Why and how is Hibernate called a lightweight tool?
This is because there are lighter weight ORM tools than Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate framework is open source and lightweight,

A framework is called lightweight when it comes to size and transparency, the term lightweight is sometimes applied to a program, protocol, device, or anything that is relatively simpler or faster or that has fewer parts than something else.

POJO stands for Plain Old Java Object and would be used to describe the same things as a "Normal Class" whereas a JavaBean follows a set of rules.
When we use POJO class in Hibernate which do not depends on Framework and it improves the testability of your code.

I believe the main selling point of "lightweight" was the use of the POJOs, Logic in the POJOs was directly executed in the same thread of control as the web layer.

The Serializable is required in POJOs if those are intended to be used in Distributed Systems and Systems which use caching and flushing into files and reading back. There is no need of Implementing any other interface or extend any class that's what makes it lightweight & that is why we can say Hibernate framework is lightweight because we make use of POJO class.